# What's the relation between time series multi-step forecast with re-estimation and forecast errors obtained by tsCV()?

Tags: r, time-series, cross-validation, forecasting

I have a monthly time series (yt) with 108 observations (1/2010 to 12/2018) which I divided into training [1:84] and test sets [85:108]. My idea is to train my model in the training set and apply it to the test set so I can compare the obtained forecasts with real observations from the test set (and do it for h = 1, 3, 6 and 12). So, I want to obtain forecasts and their errors, and use it to calculate MAE, MSE and RMSE.

**To obtain the forecasts**

I implement the code for multi-step forecasts with re-estimation provided by Dr. Rob Hyndman in https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/rolling-forecasts/:

```
h<-1 # repeat to h=3,6 and 12
train<-window(yt, end=c(2016,12))  
test<-window(yt, start=2017)  
n<-length(test)-h+1  
fit<-Arima(train, order=c(0,1,1), seasonal=list(order=c(0,1,1), period=12), method="ML") # model identified by analysing ACF and PACF of yt  
order<-arimaorder(fit)  
fcmat1<-matrix(0, nrow=n, ncol=h)  
for(i in 1:n) {  
  x<-window(yt, end=c(2016,12)+(i-1)/12)  
  refit<-Arima(x, order=order[1:3], seasonal=order[4:6])  
  fcmat1[i,]<-forecast(refit, h=h)$mean  
}
```

I can then plot the values in fcmat1 over yt and visually access the difference between the obtained forecasts and the real values of yt[85:108].

**To obtain the errors**

In the link above, Dr. Rob refers to another page related to time-series cross-validation (in https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tscv/), and so, I thought of simply doing

```
for_func<-function(x, h){forecast(fit, h=h)}  
e<-tsCV(yt, for_func, h=1)
```

and use "e" to obtain the accuracy measures, but then I get confused because it seems to me that the forecasts calculated in for_func of tsCV are different from those obtained previously (fcmat1) and so will be the errors. In the Multi-step forecasts with re-estimation approach, I'm fitting the model to the training set and then "extend" it to the remaining data. In the tsCV approach, the Arima model is being applied to all data (yt) and not just the train dataset.

If I didn't want to plot the forecasts, I would never have come with this problem and I would have used tsCV with no doubts. The same if I just want to plot the forecasts without evaluating its accuracy (I would just use the multi-step with re-estimation)

**So, my questions:**

1. Multi-step forecasting with re-estimation and tsCV are somehow related? If yes, how?
2. In practice, which of the following functions should I use to obtain the errors?

   - tsCV():

```
e1<-tsCV(yt, for_func, h=1)
  mae1<-mean(abs(e1), na.rm=TRUE)
  mse1<-mean(e1^2, na.rm=TRUE)
  rmse1<-sqrt(mse1)

#           MAE      MSE     RMSE
# h=1  40.80492 2459.470 49.59305
# h=3  43.23866 2846.406 53.35172
# h=6  46.54597 3321.426 57.63181
# h=12 51.19123 3969.944 63.00749
```

- accuracy() applied to fcmat

```
e1<-fcmat1[,1]-test
  mae1ad<-mean(abs(e1), na.rm=TRUE)
  mse1ad<-mean(e1^2, na.rm=TRUE)
  rmse1ad<-sqrt(mse1ad)

#           MAE      MSE     RMSE
# h=1  39.05335 2314.315 48.10733
# h=3  35.95370 2045.558 45.22784
# h=6  45.00950 3301.727 57.46066
# h=12 72.05596 7821.347 88.43838
```

- accuracy() as it is usually applied

```
for1<-forecast(Arima(train, order=c(0,1,1), seasonal=list(order=c(0,1,1), period=12), method="ML"),h=1)
e1ac<-accuracy(for1,test)
  mae1ac<-e1ac[6]
  mse1ac<-e1ac[4]^2
  rmse1ac<-e1ac[4]

#           MAE      MSE     RMSE
# h=1  31.93750 1020.004 31.93750
# h=3  55.97562 5097.511 71.39685
# h=6  42.35456 3628.103 60.23374
# h=12 30.84436 2201.275 46.91774
```

Can someone enlighten me about this? (and eventually alert me if I'm doing something wrong) 
Thanks

Comment: In your `for_func`, you are not using the variable `x`, which contains the data on which you should train on each rolling cross-validation step. You should replace it with `refit<-Arima(x, order=order[1:3], seasonal=order[4:6]); forecast(refit, h=h)`.

Comment: @Bas, thanks for your answer. The errors obtained are still different from those obtained with `fcmat1[,1]-test`, which is normal since different approaches are been used. Still, is the `tsCV()` approach (now corrected) better than the one adapted from `accuracy()` to obtain the errors?

Comment: What is the `length` of `for1`? I assume it has length 1 and therefore only the first value of `test` is compared to that. Could that be the case?

Comment: Yes, `for1` has length 1. (Just to clarify, when I wrote "adapted from accuracy()" in my previous comment I meant `accuracy()` applied to fcmat`)

Comment: Ah, apologies for misunderstanding. Both methods are measuring something else: the tsCV method measures how well a model would be able to forecast if it were trained on the entire training data. The other method measures how well a re-trained model would do. Depending on which method (i.e. not re-training or re-training) you are going to use to forecast, you should pick one of the two.